# Resizing partitions without moving or losing data (dual boot)

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, partitioning, ntfs, multi-boot

I have a Dell Studio 1555 currently dual booting Windows 7 & Ubuntu with a dedicated NTFS partition that serves as a bridge between OSes for my files, music, videos etc.

My Windows HDD is running low on disk space and would like to shrink the NTFS partition (bridge) and add to my Windows HDD as there is zero unallocated space left on my machine. The ext4 partition in which Ubuntu lies is small and does not need to be touched.

Is it possible to do this without reinstalling Windows and losing data?  I simply need to shrink an NTFS partition and add to my Windows HDD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows 7 include a built-in functionality in Disk Management to shrink and expand partitions. I have used this feature several times, and it works great.
[image]

Here are a couple of guides on how to resize a partition in windows 7:

1. [Resize a Partition for Free in Windows 7 or Vista](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/) [HowtoGeek.com article]
2. [How to Resize a Partition in Windows 7 or Vista by Britec](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Ue4u2mSLAo) [YouTube video tutorial]

Comment: Thanks for this, i figured i should get a second opinion before i attempted it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible to resize it without losing data.  You can simply [use Google to find out a how-to](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/).

Using software like [Partition Magic](http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/resize-partition-windows-7.htm) might make your life slightly easier, but I doubt it; as the built-in Windows 7 Disc Management software works great by itself.